# Replace all Bolded text in a Spanned String with another String?

Tags: android, string, text, replace, spanned

I have a spanned String that has some bolded text in it along with regular text. I need to replace all the bolded text with a simple regular character like "x" or "_" and then save the result to a string. I noticed there isn't a replace function for spanned strings like there is for a string; is this at all possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using a .replace() method but that wasn't supported, otherwise I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your `Spanned` text value using:

```
String text = Html.toHtml(spanned);
```

Then, you just have to replace your text between < b > and < /b > tags with "x" or "_" character, using replace() method.